# How change script insert to mysql without first row/header (DATE,ITEM)?

Tags: bash, shell, csv, ifs

```
DATE,ITEM 
2017-11-06 ,01001
2017-11-06 ,01005
2017-11-06 ,01013
```

**--- I use with this script----**

---

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS=,
while read DATE ITEM

do
        echo "INSERT INTO DB (DATE, item) VALUES ('$DATE', '$item');"
```

---

Answer (score 0):

The following command will first format your input file and replace the ' ,' by tabs for awk to be able to process it properly.

Then awk will start processing the output from the second line and then create your insert queries.

```
sed 's/ ,/\t/g' test.txt | awk '{if(NR>=2) print "INSERT INTO DB (DATE, item) VALUES(\x27"$1"\x27, \x27"$2"\x27);";}' > my_insert_queries.out
```

You can also defined another field separator for awk:

> On awk's command line, FS can be specified as `-F <sep> (or -v FS=<sep>)`

instead of using sed in order to increase the processing speed.

```
awk -F' ,' '{if(NR>=2) print "INSERT INTO DB (DATE, item) VALUES(\x27"$1"\x27, \x27"$2"\x27);";}' test.txt > my_insert_queries.out
```

Comment: There is nothing in `sed` which you can't accomplish with `awk` here.. Piping `sed` output to `awk` is an overkill and can be avoided.

Comment: yeah that's why I have proposed to change the field separator :)

Comment: Or just as well `sed -n '2,$s/\(.*\),\(.*\)/'"INSERT INTO DB(DATE, item) VALUES('\\1','\\2')/p" | sql`

Answer (score 0):

Use `awk` to sanitize the input and then pass null delimited values to a `while-loop` like below :

```
# cat 47153204.txt #note that I have added extra spaces/commas to make things more difficult

DATE,ITEM 
2017-11-06,01001
2017-11-06, 01005
2017-11-06, 01013

# awk -F '[ ,]+' 'NR>1{printf "%s\0%s\0",$1,$2}' 47153204.txt |
while IFS= read -r -d '' date time
do
# Use the date & time values to construct the query.
done
```